# Why is reloaded every list on a ajax request?

Tags: ajax, jsf-2, richfaces

I have some blocks of code, like the next one, in a form.

```
<a4j:outputPanel id="listValues">
    <a4j:repeat value="#{listBean.values}" var="aValue">
        <a4j:outputPanel rendered="#{not empty aValue.value}">
            <h:selectBooleanCheckbox id="selectRecordCheck"
                value="#{listBean.aValueSelectedMap[aValue.value]}">
                <a4j:ajax event="valueChange" execute="@this"
                    render="tagsValues, listValues"
                    listener="#{listBean.listenerValueChange}" />
                <a4j:param name="id" value="#{aValue.value}" />
                <a4j:param name="value"
                    value="#{listBean.aValueSelectedMap[aValue.value]}" />
            </h:selectBooleanCheckbox>
            <h:outputLabel value="#{aValue.label}" />
            <br />
        </a4j:outputPanel>
    </a4j:repeat>
</a4j:outputPanel>
<a4j:outputPanel id="tagsValues">
    <table>
        <a4j:repeat value="#{listBean.listaVirtualEstadoSeleccionados}"
            var="tag">
            <tr>
                <td><h:outputText styleClass="tags" value="#{tag}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </a4j:repeat>
    </table>
</a4j:outputPanel>
```

The problem is that clicking on a checkBox reload the lists of the other groups of checkBoxes (other managedBean properties are called).

How can avoid this behavior?

Running on a JBoss AS6.1.0, Mojarra 2.0.3, RichFaces 4.3.7
Thx

Answer (score 0):

Ok,

We had the Mojarra 2.0.3-b05 version. I've upgraded to 2.0.11 (i've found something about a bug on the 2.1 in 2011 that could be relationated) and added to the a4j:ajax element the following code

```
immediate="true" limitRender="true" bypassUpdates="true"
```

Maybe adding the attributes would be enough, but i think that upgrading the jsf version is a good idea anyway.

PD: I suppose that there is a bug, because I think that it has not sense that behavior.